I need help with this indirect rule question. I can’t seem to figure it out and it’s the last one in my lab if anyone can help me!
((P & (Q → R)) → S)
(¬P ∨ (Q ∨ S))
I need help with this indirect rule if anyone can help me out!

Well, if you expand it out with A -> B == ~A v B, and use DeMorgan's, you get ~P v Q~R v S. Then because Q~R implies Q, you get ~P v Q v S (using constructive dilemma). That's the general idea, perhaps you can translate it to whatever software you are using.

To the upvoters :-) I am really interested into knowing what someone can find interesting into a picture of a screen. Do you really think that it is worth to be read?

Please edit your question and just transcribe the two lines of text that are relevant so we can easily read them, copy them, they can be searched, so your post works with slow connections and text-based browsers and so it is accessible to people using screen readers.

We're not going to do your homework for you, but here are some hints.
When solving natural deduction problems, it is a good idea to learn how to prove a few basic things that you can then use as building blocks in a longer proof. In particular, you should learn how to prove the following:

The law of excluded middle, i.e. that P ∨ ¬P is a theorem.
The rule of material implication, i.e. that P → Q is logically equivalent to ¬P ∨ Q.
De Morgan's rules, i.e. that ¬(P ∨ Q) is logically equivalent to ¬P & ¬Q and also that ¬(P & Q) is logically equivalent to ¬P ∨ ¬Q.
The distributivity rules for & and ∨, i.e. P & (Q ∨ R) is logically equivalent to (P & Q) ∨ (P & R); also P ∨ (Q & R) is logically equivalent to (P ∨ Q) & (P ∨ R).

Once you can do those, you can attack your problem like this:

Assume the negation of the conclusion you are trying to prove.
Use De Morgan and &E to derive P and ¬Q and ¬S.
From ¬Q, use ∨I and the rule of material implication to derive Q → R.
From P and Q → R and your given premise, derive S.
You now have both S and ¬S, so use ⊥I and ¬I to discharge your assumption and introduce its negation.
Use ¬E to get your conclusion.

